# Some iOS 4.2 devices shutting down WiFi early?

Tags: ios, uikit, ios4

I write an app that requires a persistent WiFi connection, and to facilitate that connection being as persistent as possible, I have UIRequiresPersistentWifi set to yes in my Info.plist, and I recommend leaving the app 'open' when the user presses the the hold button.

However, on iPod touches (I have a 2G one and a 4G one for testing) running iOS 4.2.1, the device seems to shut down the WiFi connection *much* earlier after the device is put to sleep than it did on earlier iOS versions. I think it's on the order of 60 seconds.

I don't believe Apple has made any firm commitments on how it handles powering down network connections, but I was under the impression it was longer, intended to be longer, and it was something we could rely on. Does anyone have any input on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears after some reading/research, it looks like Apple's philosophy is that the WiFi network shouldn't be relied upon: "Note: Note that even when UIRequiresPersistentWiFi has a value of true, it has no effect when the device is idle (that is, screen-locked). The application is considered inactive, and although it may function on some levels, it has no Wi-Fi connection." - (from the iOS Application Programming Guide).

I'm guessing I'm seeing the different behavior on an iPhone because, also, in the iOS Application Programming Guide - "Connect to the network using the Wi-Fi radios whenever possible. Wi-Fi uses less power and is preferred over the cellular radios."